# how to add {author}, {tableofcontents} and {date} for each {chapter} or {section}

Tags: xetex

I was composing a book (using xelatex) that each chapter comes from different author, is there any environments/packages that can put these message *near* each chapter/section instead of the heading pages of the book?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `combine` class (which also makes use of the packages `combinet`, `combnat` and `combcite` to achieve the results one would expect when preparing a volume composed of different articles by different authors).

I have never used it myself, but it seems to be good enough for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I will only able to advise you with tableofcontent for each chapter. I use the library `minitoc` for doing this. Please see to code below. In each chapter, you must add the command `\minitoc`. I usually also sets the counter `tocdepth` and `secnumdepth`. I hope it helps at least part of your problem

```
\documentclass[%
    ,fontsize=12pt      % 
    ,b4paper, pagesize
    ,captions=nooneline
    ,DIV=11             % calculation of the typearea
    ,BCOR=12mm          % binding correction for the left/inner side
]{scrbook}

 \usepackage[x11names, dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}  % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor/ 
% ~~~~~~~~~~~ Hyperlinks ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
\usepackage[xetex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={Athor name},
            pdftitle={Book name},
            pdfsubject={My study notes},
            pdfkeywords={linear algebra, math, electronics},
            pdfpagelayout={TwoPageLeft}, % Displays two pages, odd-numbered pages to the left 
            pdfcreator={Xelatex}
            bookmarks={true},            %  A set of Acrobat bookmarks are written
            colorlinks={true},           %  Colors the text of links and anchors. 
            linkcolor={NavyBlue},        %  Color for normal internal links.
            anchorcolor={black},         %  Color for anchor text.
            filecolor={cyan},            %  Color for URLs which open local files.
            menucolor={red},             %  Color for Acrobat menu items.
            runcolor={blue},             %  Color for run links (launch annotations).
            urlcolor={NavyBlue},         %  Color for linked URLs. 
            citecolor={CornflowerBlue}          
           }
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nohints]{minitoc}              % Control the fonts and formatting used in the table of
                                            % contents.

\begin{document}
% =============================== TOC ============================================================= 
% this sets the depth to which things are listed in the table of contents 
% (Chapters =0, Sections =1, etc)
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} 
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
% =============================== BOOK ============================================================ 
  \chapter{chapter 1}
    \minitoc
      \section {chap 1 sec 1}
        \lipsum[1] 
    \section {chap 1 sec 2}
    \section {chap 1 sec 3}
  \chapter{chapter 2}
    \minitoc 
    \section {chap 1 sec 1}
    \section {chap 1 sec 2}
    \section {chap 1 sec 3}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]